# Windows: ipv6 version of "netsh int ipv4 install"

Tags: windows-10, tcpip

I need to reinstall TCP/IP V6 protocols on my Windows 10 64 bit PC.

I know I can do this for TCP/IP V4 using `netsh int ipv4 install` in an elevated `cmd` prompt.

When I run `netsh int ipv6 install` I receive

```
The following command was not found: int ipv6 install.
```

What is the equivalent for TCP/IP V6 please?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I cannot find install option available for `netsh interface ipv6 /?` and [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736546(v=vs.85).aspx#netsh_interface_ipv6_install) shows that is available. Weird

Comment: It used to exist. But AFAIK "TCP/IPv6" has become _required_ in a recent Windows release?

Comment: @grawity. Even if it is required, there should be an option to _re_-install in case something goes wrong.